# How to eliminate RubyMine false "No such file to load" errors

Tags: rubymine

I've recently installed RubyMine on a second machine and cloned a GitHub repository there.

My application runs exactly the same as on the first machine, but the RM code inspection result is radically different: I get dozens of "No such file to load" errors.

This even though the application runs fine both from the command line and from RM.

In dialog Run/Debug Configurations, I have specified load paths (-I. -I..) in the Ruby arguments.

Does the code inspection not honor the configuration?  Or perhaps it's using a different configuration?

Answer (score 7):

A bit late, but you may need to mark the directories that are load path roots in your app within the Rubymine tree - right click and do **"Mark Directory As/Load Path Root"**.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing, that worked great for me!

Answer (score 2):

For me the other solutions did not work. However, the problem was that RubyMine detected the wrong ruby version - while `rvm` for the project was ruby `2.4.1`, in RubyMine it defaulted to the last version it had (2.4.2). So going to **RubyMine > Preferences > Ruby SDK & Gems** and changing the version for the project to the correct one solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "Mark Directory As/Load Path Root" action, this will apply for IDE autocompletion only. It will not be propagated onto the interpreter (as it would be in PyCharm with Python).

You have to either keep using the `-I` switch, or configure `$LOAD_PATH` in your code, or (preferably) set up a Gem project with bundler support. You can then configure the path in a `gemspec` file. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/creating-gem-project.html.

Sources:

1. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206741945-Load-Path-not-working-at-all-
2. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206727915-Building-RubyGems-lib-in-load-path-

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing Project Path Mappings and set relative **Local Path** and **Remote Path** to get it to work.[image]